# Sieve of eratosthenes: My optimized version

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I wrote a simple prime number program that checks if a number is prime or not using sieve of eratosthenes, I also wrote an optimized version that only generates the `sieve_arr` when the `val` exceeds the length of `sieve_arr`.

### sieve.py

```
# sieve.py

from array import array
from math import sqrt

def sieve(n=80):
    """Sieve of Erathosthenes"""

    sieve_arr = array('i', [True for _ in range(n+1)])
    sieve_arr_length = len(sieve_arr)
    
    for i in range(2, int(sqrt(sieve_arr_length)) + 1):
        if sieve_arr[i]:
            for j in range(i + i, n + 1, i):
                sieve_arr[j] = False;

    return sieve_arr
```

### prime.py

```
# prime.py

import timeit
from array import array
from sieve import sieve

sieve_arr = array('i')

def isprime(val):
    global sieve_arr 
    if val >= len(sieve_arr):
        sieve_arr = sieve(val * 2)
    
    return sieve_arr[val]

def isprime2(val):
    return sieve(val)[val]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TEST1 = '''
from prime import isprime
for i in range(1, 10001):
    isprime(i)
    '''

    TEST2 = '''
from prime import isprime2
for i in range(1, 10001):
    isprime2(i)
    '''

    tt1 = timeit.repeat(stmt=TEST2, repeat = 5, number=1)
    print('prime Time taken: ', min(tt1))
    tt2 = timeit.repeat(stmt=TEST1, repeat = 5, number=1)
    print('Optimized prime Time taken: ', min(tt2))
```

I ran the test and had the following results

```
prime Time taken:  9.446519022000302
Optimized prime Time taken:  0.002043106000201078
```

Note: I didn't check for 0 and 1 in `isprime()` and `isprime2()` which aren't prime number, I wrote the code with performance in mind.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that 0 and 1 are prime.

Comment: They aren't, I was mostly writing it for performance.

Comment: Why use `array`, instead of basic lists?

Comment: I don't understand the rationale behind this `sieve_arr = sieve(val * 2)`, If you want to check `val` is prime or not, generate values until `val` why `val*2`? If you want to check if a number is prime or not, why use sieve of Eratosthenes in the first place? Check this out [`Primality test, 6k+1 optimization python code`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Python_Code).

Comment: Further optimizing your code change this to `for j in range(i + i, n + 1, i)` -> `for j in range(i * i, n + 1, i)`. Read about it [`Sieve of Eratosthenes`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Overview)

Comment: Since Python 3.8 you can use [math.isqrt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isqrt) instead of `int(math.sqrt(...))`

Comment: @Ch3steR The rationale seems to be similar to how `list.append` overallocates in order to make subsequent calls instant. This overcomputes to make subsequent calls instant. That's the optimization, and why that's so much faster in their test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sieve can be optimized further.  Pull the case for `i = 2` outside of the `for` loop and then change the `for` loop to only check odd indexes.  Also use slice assignment instead of a nested loop.  This code is 10x faster (<100ms to sieve primes to 1M compared to >1s for your sieve).

```
def sieve2a(n=80):
    """Sieve of Erathosthenes"""

    sieve_arr = [True]*n
    sieve_arr[0] = sieve_arr[1] = False
    
    sieve_arr[4::2] = [False]*len(range(4, len(sieve_arr), 2))
    for i in range(3, int(sqrt(len(sieve_arr))) + 1, 2):
        if sieve_arr[i]:
            sieve_arr[i*i::i] = [False]*len(range(i*i, len(sieve_arr), i))

    return sieve_arr
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `sieve_arr[0] = sieve_arr[1] = False`? Seems to be an attempt to correctly support n=0 and n=1, but if I try those, it of course crashes with an IndexError.

Comment: @superbrain, Its just to keep the array in synch, so `sieve_arr[n]` is True if `n` is prime.

Answer (score 5):

## Built-in functions

As mentioned by Marc, Since Python 3.8 you can use [math.isqrt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isqrt).  This is faster.  It is also guaranteed to be accurate when the size of the argument exceeds the number of bits of mantissa in a float.

## Type coercion

```
sieve_arr = array('i', [True for _ in range(n+1)])
```

Your array is declared to hold `'i'` values: integers.  But you are trying to storing boolean values in the array.  This necessitates an unnecessary conversion from `True` and `False` to `1` and `0`.

## Underused variable

The value `sieve_arr_length` is used once.  It effectively holds `n + 1`.
In fact, `sieve_arr_length = n + 1` might be a more efficient way to initialize it, rather than asking the array for its length.  Then instead of recomputing `n+1` each time the `j` loop starts, you could simply use `sieve_arr_length`.

## Special case even numbers

Every even number greater than 2 is not prime.  There is no need to check for these.  You could simply start your `i` loop at `3`, instead of `2`, and go up by twos to check only the odd numbers greater than 1.

Starting the `j` loop at `i+i`, or `i*2` is an optimization, but not enough of one.  By the time you're checking `13`, you've already eliminated `3*13`, `5*13`, `7*13`, and `11*13` because you've eliminated multiples of smaller primes.  You can simply start at `i*i`.

Plus, if you're only checking the odd prime candidates (because you've special-cased the even), you don't need to eliminate `14*13`, `16*13`, `18*13` and so on, because those are guaranteed to be even. Your step size can be `2*i`, and eliminate half of the redundant assignments.

```
    # Odd prime candidate sieve ...
    for i in range(3, isqrt(sieve_arr_length) + 1, 2):
        if sieve_arr[i]:
            for j in range(i * i, sieve_arr_length, 2 * i):
                sieve_arr[j] = 0;
```

## Memory

The `array('i', ...)` uses 4 or 8 (depending on architecture) bytes per element in the array.  [RootTwo's solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/252875/100620) uses a `list` structure, instead of the `array`.  This will increase the amount of storage required for the sieve, since a list must store a pointer in each list element.

Using a `bytearray` instead of an `array('i', ...)` would reduce your memory usage, down to 1 byte per sieve element, allowing you to maintain a larger sieve.

```py
def ajneufeld_bytearray(n=80):
    """Sieve of Erathosthenes"""

    prime = bytearray((0, 1)) * ((n + 1) // 2)
    prime[1] = 0
    prime[2] = 1
    for i in range(3, isqrt(n) + 1, 2):
        if prime[i]:
            prime[i*i::2*i] = bytes(len(range(i*i, n, 2*i)))

    return prime
```

You can further pack 8 flags into each byte, dramatically decreasing the size of your sieve even further, but this bit packing would be complex to implement yourself.  Fortunately it has already been done as a nice package: [`bitarray`](https://pypi.org/project/bitarray/).

## bitarray implementation

The `bitarray` package has nice bitslice assignment operators.  RootTwo's slice assignment:

```
sieve_arr[i*i::i] = [False]*len(range(i*i, len(sieve_arr), i))
```

is much easier with `bitarray`.  The equivalent statement would be:

```
sieve_arr[i*i::i] = False
```

assigning `False` to each bit in the slice.

```py
from bitarray import bitarray
from math import isqrt

def ajneufeld(n=80):
    """Sieve of Erathosthenes"""

    prime = bitarray(n)
    prime.setall(False)
    prime[3::2] = True

    prime[2] = True
    for candidate in range(3, isqrt(n) + 1, 2):
        if prime[candidate]:
            prime[candidate*candidate::2*candidate] = False

    return prime
```

Test code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from timeit import timeit
from sys import getsizeof

if __name__ == '__main__':

    candidates = (theprogrammer, roottwo, ajneufeld_bytearray, ajneufeld_bitarray)
    limits = [10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10_000, 30_000, 100_000, 300_000]

    print("Memory usage:")
    for candidate in candidates:
        result = candidate(100_000)
        print(f"  {candidate.__name__:19} {getsizeof(result):6}")

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    for candidate in candidates:
        times = [ timeit(lambda: candidate(limit), number=1) for limit in limits ]
        ax.plot(limits, times, '-+', label=candidate.__name__)

    ax.legend()
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.show()
```

Output:

```
Memory usage:
  theprogrammer       400068
  roottwo             800056
  ajneufeld_bytearray 100057
  ajneufeld_bitarray   12564
```

[image]

Comment: Woow. This is a great improvement.

Comment: IIRC, using `bitarray` would nearly double the access time compared to a regular `list` or `bytearray`. You may want to explicitly mention that time-memory trade-off when you introduce `bitarray`.

Comment: @GZ0 `bytearray` is only better that `bitarray` for sieves from 30_000 to 3_000_000.  `bitarray` leads at the smaller sizes and larger sizes (on my laptop, Python 3.8 64-bit, bitarray 1.6.1) .  Agreed, access to individual bits should be slower than to bytes, but L1 & L2 cache sizes probably start to play a role, and using 1/8th the memory gives `bitarray` an advantage there.

Comment: Correct me if am wrong, I don't think in a list, elements  holds a pointer to the next element. A list uses array as its internal structure.

Comment: @theProgrammer A Python `list` is an array of object _references_.  The same object can be stored in many different variables or structures (like lists, dictionaries, tuples).  Internally, this is accomplished via pointers. A `list` is implemented (CPython) as an array of object pointers.  Not to be confused with a linked list, where each object has a pointer to the next.  Try calling `sys.getsizeof(x)` for lists of different sizes.  The result will depend only on `len(x)`, regardless of the size or kind of each element in the list.

Comment: As you said, `it is an array of object references`, then I think there is no overhead of an additional pointer.

Comment: @theProgrammer  Yes.  Object references are pointers.  Ergo, Python lists are implemented as an array of pointers.

Comment: Run `from array import array; from sys import getsizeof; print(getsizeof(array('i', [0]*10)) - getsizeof(array('i', [0]*9)), getsizeof([0]*10) - getsizeof([0]*9))` and you get `4 8`, demonstrating that an `array('i',...)` uses 4 bytes per integer, the list uses 8 bytes per element.  Double the memory. The output in my post shows 400068 for your `array('i', ...)` implementation, and `800056` for RootTwo's list implementation.  Double the memory.  The [`documentation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) title: "Efficient arrays of numeric values_"! You think "list has no overhead"?

Comment: Great resource @AJNeufeld.